# Using Cython to wrap Windows standard API

Tags: python, winapi, cython, linker-errors

I would like to use cython to write an extension that uses some of standard Windows API. As a first step I read the [Windows and wide character APIs](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/strings.html#windows-and-wide-character-apis) documentation and so I have set up two simple files:

- *hello.pyx* with the cython code
- *setup.py* to build the extension

**hello.pyx**

```
import sys

cdef extern from "Windows.h":
    ctypedef Py_UNICODE WCHAR
    ctypedef const WCHAR* LPCWSTR
    ctypedef void* HWND

    int __stdcall MessageBoxW(HWND hWnd, LPCWSTR lpText, LPCWSTR lpCaption, int uType)

def say_hello_to(name):
    print("Hello %s!" % name)

def msg():
    title = u"Windows Interop Demo - Python %d.%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:3]
    MessageBoxW(NULL, u"Hello Cython \u263a", title, 0)
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
  name='Hello world app',
  ext_modules=cythonize("hello.pyx"),
)
```

Whenever I try to build the extension with this command

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

I get the following output

```
running build_ext
building 'hello' extension
D:\Programmi (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -ID:\Python35\include -ID:\Python35\include "-ID:\Programmi (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-ID:\Programmi (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /Tchello.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Release\hello.obj
hello.c
D:\Programmi (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:D:\Python35\Libs "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\Lorenzo\Python Virtualenvs\Cython\libs" "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\Lorenzo\Python Virtualenvs\Cython\PCbuild\win32" "/LIBPATH:D:\Programmi (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB" "/LIBPATH:D:\Programmi (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86" /EXPORT:PyInit_hello build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\hello.obj /OUT:C:\Users\Lorenzo\Dropbox\Pycharm\Cython\hello.cp35-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\hello.cp35-win32.lib
   Creating library build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\hello.cp35-win32.lib and object build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\hello.cp35-win32.exp
hello.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__MessageBoxW@16
C:\Users\Lorenzo\Dropbox\Pycharm\Cython\hello.cp35-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error: command 'D:\\Programmi (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

I've tried to google for the error message

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__MessageBoxW@16
```

but I am not sure on how to fix this for cython.

If I strip away the msg() function defined in the hello.pyx file the extension compiles fine and it also works so I assume I am doing something wrong with the C typedefs, but I don't understand what.

After @DavidW comment I was able to fix the issue changing the setup.py file like the one below.

**setup.py (revisited)**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [
    Extension("hello", ["hello.pyx"], libraries=["user32"])
]
setup(
    name="Hello world app",
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions), requires=['Cython']
)
```

What made the difference is the "libraries=["user32"]" import

Comment: You need to [link it against the appropriate library in setup.py](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html#configuring-the-c-build). I don't know which library that is for you though

Comment: I followed your suggestion and reviewed the setup.py accordingly and now it works fine, thank you very much @DavidW

Comment: @LorenzoPersichetti Could you please show the reviewed setup.py. I have a similar problem but whatever I change, it doesn't work.

Comment: @PieterJanBonestroo I've updated the original post with my revisited setup.py that fixed the issue for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: @LorenzoPersichetti It helped! That was exactly what I needed, thanks!